# Analyze the runtime of following recurrence

Tags: algorithm, runtime, recurrence

a.T(n)=T(n/2)+n;T(1)=1

Since i know the runtime of T(n)=2T(n/2)+n is O(nlogn), I think the answer is O(n^2), but the correct answer is O(n)

b.T(n)=2T(n/2)+1;T(1)=1

Since i know the runtime of T(n)=2T(n/2)+n is O(logn), I think the answer is O(log n), but the correct answer is O(n)

I'm really confused, since T(n)='work per level' x 'number of levels'.
I think the number of work level in b is O(logn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a trick substitution

[image]

... if you see any terms like T(n / 2) etc.

a)

[image]

b)

[image]